# Can't use zulucrypt-cli as regular user

Tags: command-line, permissions, encryption, truecrypt

I have both Ubuntu 18 (bionic) and 19 (eoan). I installed zulucrypt-cli from the regular repositories:

```
apt-get install zulucrypt-cli
```

When I try to run it as my regular user, I get the error:

```
ERROR: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted
```

This happens even if I don't pass any parameters. I want to decrypt a regular TrueCrypt file I have:

```
zuluCrypt-cli -o -d my_secret_file.tc -e ro -m zctest
```

The command above works fine when I run it as root. But then, obviously, regular users don't have access to it. When I search the web for the error, I don't get anything associated with zuluCrypt. I found that the problem could be related to the [binary capabilities](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919724/rsync-error-setgroup-failed). I checked that, it seems zuluCrypt doesn't have any:

```
root@PC1:~# getcap /usr/bin/zuluCrypt-cli 
root@PC1:~#
```

I could set them myself, but I don't want to do that except as a last resort. I'm not familiar with that command and I don't know which security implications it would have. I'm also not sure that this would solve it.

In any case, I'm just sceptical that the package is issued without permissions for regular users, which makes me wonder if something wrong happened to my installation. I'd appreciate if I could get a confirmation or help to confirm myself that the official package indeed doesn't come with permissions to run as regular user, and if I could get help properly setting the permissions so that I can run it as a regular user without creating a security issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: As described in the question, the same happens in my ubuntu 18.04, whose EOL is 2023, so it should stilll be on topic. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I have both Ubuntu 18 (bionic) and 19 (eoan). I did the same thing in both, got the same results in both. You don't need to comment on eoan if you don't want, you can help me with bionic only, that works for me. :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm more familiar with desktops & servers or *yy.mm* releases rather than *snap* based *yy* specialist releases like Ubuntu Core 18.

Comment: So you must be familiar with ubuntu 18.04, and hopefully you can help. ^_^ Looking forward to your recommendations. :)